# Is it possible to inject a control into the body of the page from the code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

I have a dnn module, and I have a requirement where I need to inject some HTML elements in the body tag of the page.

I tried:

```
HtmlGenericControl divControl = new HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
divControl.ID = "divControl";
this.Page.Controls.AddAt(0, divControl);
```

the code above cause the HTML to look like this:

```
<div id="xxxxxx_divControl"></div><!DOCTYPE html>
<html  lang="en-US">
<head id="Head">...
```

There is no body property on the Page, so is there a way to make the div render in the body tag? (like shown below)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  lang="en-US">
<head id="Head">...
</head>
<body>
<div id="xxxxxx_divControl"></div>
....
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `runat="server"` and an ID to the body tag. Then add your control to the body's control collection. But, depending on your Page Lifecycle, it may not end up where you want it to be, so a Placeholder is still the preferred way.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to add it to the `Page` controls, but to the controls of a container within the page.  Use a `PlaceHolder` for this.  Just add the `PlaceHolder` control to your page where you want to inject content:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="somePlaceHolder" />
```

Then you would reference that in your code-behind:

```
HtmlGenericControl divControl = new HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
divControl.ID = "divControl";
this.somePlaceHolder.Controls.AddAt(0, divControl);
```

Comment: This is a great solution, but unfortunately not exactly what I am looking for.  I need to do this with adding any PlaceHolder controls.  There are multiple modules that share the code of this module, so I really cannot achieve what I want using this method.

Comment: @malkassem: Another option would be to make some other page element into a server-side control and use that instead.  The point is that you need to be able to *identify* and *reference* the location in the page using server-side code, which means that location needs to be a server-side element.  If you have to use client-side elements then you'd likely need to reference them with JavaScript and either store the content in a JavaScript variable or make an AJAX call to fetch it and add it to the specified location with client-side code.

Comment: Another great idea, but does that mean it is not possible to just somehow reference the body element?  How come there is a clear access to head element and not body I wonder?

Comment: @malkassem: Where do you see access to the `head` element?  If you've made that work, post the code and perhaps there's a way to modify it to use the `body` element instead.  You can also try inspecting the current contents of the `Controls` collection to which you're adding and see if it discerns between different client-side elements.  If it does, you might be able to write some logic to determine where to place your content.  It's a bit of a hack though.

Comment: there is a property on the page object called Header.  If you add a control to the controls collection of that object, it would show up in head element.